# How to paginate a list of posts belonging to a specific category in GatsbyJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pagination, graphql, gatsby

I have developed a blog with Gatsby JS and I managed to add categories to each markdown file so that I can create pages by querying a specific category and list all the posts related to that category. 
Now, I'm trying to add pagination to avoid an infinite list of posts inside each category page.

I have been following the official guide here: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-pagination/

And this is the code I came up with:

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path')
const _ = require("lodash")
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")

exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
const {createPage} = actions

const articleTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/article.js`)
const categoryTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/category.js")

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(
      graphql(
          `
            {
                allMarkdownRemark(
                    sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
                    limit: 2000
                ) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            html
                            id
                            frontmatter {
                                path
                                title
                                categories
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    `).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
            reject(result.errors)
        }

        const articles = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges
        const articlesPerPage = 6
        const numPages = Math.ceil(articles.length / articlesPerPage)

        //Creating a page for each article
        articles.forEach(({ node }) => {
            createPage({
            path: node.frontmatter.path,
            component: articleTemplate,
            //context: {}, // additional data can be passed via context
            })
        })

        // Categories pages:
        let categories = []
        // Iterate through each article, putting all found categories into `categories`
        _.each(articles, edge => {
            if (_.get(edge, "node.frontmatter.categories")) {
                categories = categories.concat(edge.node.frontmatter.categories)
            }
        })


        Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((category, _, i) => {
            createPage({
              path: i === 0 ? `/${_.kebabCase(category)}/` : `/${_.kebabCase(category)}/${i + 1}`,
              component: categoryTemplate,
              context: {
                limit: articlesPerPage,
                skip: i * articlesPerPage,
                category,
              },
            })
        })
    })
)
})
```

/templates/categories.js

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Layout from '../layouts/layout'
import ArticleCard from '../components/articles/articlecard'

// Components
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"

const _ = require("lodash")

const Categories = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  const { category } = pageContext
  const { edges } = data.allMarkdownRemark

  return (
    <Layout>
        <section class="hero is-info is-medium has-text-centered">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="title is-top">
                        {category}
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="columns is-multiline">
                    {edges.map(({ node }) => {
                        const { path, title, date } = node.frontmatter
                        return (
                            <div class="column is-half">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <p class="card-header-content">{date}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                    <Link to={_.kebabCase(category)}><span class="tag is-success has-padding">{category}</span></Link>
                                        <Link to={path}>
                                            <h2 class="title is-4">{title}</h2>
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-item"><Link to={path}><div class="button is-success is-inverted is-fullwidth">Read</div></Link></div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-item"><Link to={path}><div class="button is-info is-inverted is-fullwidth">Share on Linkedin</div></Link></div>
                                    </div>        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

Categories.propTypes = {
  pageContext: PropTypes.shape({
    category: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
  data: PropTypes.shape({
   allMarkdownRemark: PropTypes.shape({
      totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      edges: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
          node: PropTypes.shape({
            frontmatter: PropTypes.shape({
              path: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
              title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            }),
          }),
        }).isRequired
      ),
    }),
  }),
}

export default Categories

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!, $category: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { categories: { in: [$category] } } }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            title
            path
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

This does not work and it is now throwing the error: error gatsby-node.js returned an error, TypeError: _.kebabCase is not a function

However kebabCase was used smoothly before modifying the query to add pagination, so I don't think the problem is actually there.

Does anyone have any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the variable "underscore" twice:
1- from the lodash library
2- from the forEach function:

```
Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((category, _, i)
```

just change the the second variable to another arbitrary name like this:

```
Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((category, otherName, i)
```