# What am I misunderstanding in gatsby-node when trying to build a template page for categories or tags?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, categories

Trying to learn Gatsby I'm confused what I'm doing wrong when it comes to building a paginated page for a category. If a post has a category created from the frontmatter of:

```
---
date: '2017-08-10'
title: 'Sweet Pandas Eating Sweets'
slug: 'sweet-pandas-eating-sweets'
description: 'Something different to post'
category: ['sweet', 'yep', 'two']
tags: ['3', '2']
---
```

in my *gatsby-node.js* I dont have any issues (or thrown issues I should say) with single post generation but the console reads:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

when the category is clicked but not when the `<Link>` is clicked to go to the single post, the file:

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            frontmatter {
              title
              slug
              tags
              category
              date
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (data.errors) {
    console.error(data.errors)
    throw data.errors
  }

  // const tagSet = new Set()
  // const categorySet = new Set()

  data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.frontmatter.slug
    const id = edge.node.id
    actions.createPage({
      path: slug,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/singlePost.js`),
      context: { id },
    })
  })

  const postPerPage = 3
  const numPages = Math.ceil(data.allMdx.edges.length / postPerPage)
  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/` : `/${i + 1}`,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`),
      context: {
        limit: postPerPage,
        skip: i * postPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

and in `templates/category.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

// Components
import Layout from '../components/Layout'

const category = ({ location, pageContext, data }) => {
  const { currentPage, numPages } = pageContext
  const isFirst = currentPage === 1
  const isLast = currentPage === numPages
  const prevPage = currentPage - 1 === 1 ? '/' : `/${currentPage - 1}`
  const nextPage = `/${currentPage + 1}`
  const posts = data.allMdx.edges

  console.log('data', data)
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>categories</Layout>
    </>
  )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query CategoryQuery($id: String!, $skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allMdx(
      sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
      skip: $skip
      limit: $limit
      filter: { frontmatter: { category: { eq: $id } } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
            category
            date
            description
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default category
```

In Graph*i*QL both my queries work, example with filtering for just a category:

```
{
"id":"two"
}
```

query:

```
query CategoryQuery($id: String!) {
  allMdx(
    sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}
    filter: {frontmatter: {category: {eq: $id}}}
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        frontmatter {
          title
          category
          date
          description
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Research:

- [Creating Tags Pages for Blog Posts](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/)
- [How to paginate a list of posts belonging to a specific category in GatsbyJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457058/how-to-paginate-a-list-of-posts-belonging-to-a-specific-category-in-gatsbyjs)
- [Wordpress + Gatsby: List all posts for each categories?](https://www.reddit.com/r/gatsbyjs/comments/cwn2ev/wordpress_gatsby_list_all_posts_for_each/)
- [gatsby-advanced-starter](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter/blob/master/gatsby-node.js)

Why when I click on a category from a post if I add it up in the header it goes to a 404 Page and indicates there is no page yet for `/category`?

Edit:

Stripped down sandbox of what's going on and the issue:

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Tried changing the node from the `id` to the `slug` and the result is the same:

```
  tagsQuery.data.allMdx.edges.forEach(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.frontmatter.slug
    actions.createPage({
      path: `category/${slug}`,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/Category.js`),
      context: { slug },
    })
  })
```

from the 404 page, under pages it shows:

```
/category/undefined
/404/
/
/404.html
/post-slug
/post-slug
```

Comment: eh, `console.log(slug)` ? `tagsQuery` doesn't contain `slug` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and tests in Graph*i*QL I found `distinct` in allMDX and I was able to query the frontmatter category or tag:

*foo.mdx* frontmatter:

```markdown
---
date: '2017-08-10'
title: 'Sweet Pandas Eating Sweets'
slug: 'sweet-pandas-eating-sweets'
description: 'Something different to post'
category: ['sweet', 'yep', 'two']
---
```

gatsby-node.js:

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const catsQuery = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/" } }) {
        distinct(field: frontmatter___category)
      }
    }
  `)

  catsQuery.data.allMdx.distinct.forEach(category => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: `/category/${category}`,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`),
      context: { category },
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that may cause issues:

- Your `templates/category` component must be capitalized:

  ```
    const Category = ({ location, pageContext, data }) => {
    const { currentPage, numPages } = pageContext
    const isFirst = currentPage === 1
    const isLast = currentPage === numPages
    const prevPage = currentPage - 1 === 1 ? '/' : `/${currentPage - 1}`
    const nextPage = `/${currentPage + 1}`
    const posts = data.allMdx.edges

    console.log('data', data)
    return (
      <>
        <Layout>categories</Layout>
      </>
    )
  }
  ```

  Otherwise, React won't be able to infer and create a valid component.
- Before going into paginating your categories or tags, I would try to create a step-by-step approach, creating successfully the category template. You are re-using the same query to create as well posts and categories but you are never looping to create a category. I would segregate the logic into two separate GraphQL queries:

  ```
    exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql }) => {
      const postsQuery = await graphql(`
        query {
          allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                frontmatter {
                  title
                  slug
                  tags
                  category
                  date
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `)

      const tagsQuery = await graphql(`
        query {
          allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                frontmatter {
                  tags
                  category
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `)


      if (postsQuery.data.errors || tagsQuery.data.errors) {
        console.error(data.errors)
        throw data.errors
      }

      // const tagSet = new Set()
      // const categorySet = new Set()

      tagsQuery.data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => {
        const slug = edge.node.frontmatter.slug
        const id = edge.node.id
        actions.createPage({
          path: slug, // or `category/${slug}`
          component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`),
          context: { id },
        })
      })


      postsQuery.data.allMdx.edges.map(edge => {
        const slug = edge.node.frontmatter.slug
        const id = edge.node.id
        actions.createPage({
          path: slug,
          component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/singlePost.js`),
          context: { id },
        })
      })
      /*
      const postPerPage = 3
      const numPages = Math.ceil(data.allMdx.edges.length / postPerPage)
      Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
        actions.createPage({
          path: i === 0 ? `/` : `/${i + 1}`,
          component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/category.js`),
          context: {
            limit: postPerPage,
            skip: i * postPerPage,
            numPages,
            currentPage: i + 1,
          },
        })
      })*/
    }
  ```

  To check the created pages, you can always look for the 404 page in `gatsby develop` (`localhost:8000/someOddString`) mode, which by default, prints all the created pages.